# C Editor or Compiler for Windows CE

Tags: c, compiler-construction, windows-ce

Someone can please answer to me, if have any Editor or Compiler to C language for Windows CE 3.1( Jornada 720 - HPC 2000 ), because i'm a Visual Basic developer and i have buyed a book of C only for play with this language in my free time, and the time that is free to me i'm using my Jornada 720, but remember that i've want something like PocketC or only a compiler but free, and remember to, that i've want it to be onboard, not in to compile in my computer, Thanks. Sorry about my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These links might be useful to you:

[Google Windows+CE+c+IDE](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=Windows+CE+c+IDE)

[Free C++ (and C) Programming Tools](http://www.freebyte.com/programming/cpp/)

[Introduction to Development Tools for Windows Mobile-based Devices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms838188.aspx)

eMbedded Visual C++ might be an appropriate tool for you in Windows. I've used it in the past to develop on a Windows CE device.

Comment: Hello mezoid,

I've looked in the links, but you can post something like PocketC but free. http://www.orbworks.com/pcce/index.html . Thanks, please vote up to my question!

Comment: Free is a pretty tough ask for functionality that wasn't common in the first place (assuming you're wanting the embedded editor and compiler mentioned in PocketC).

Comment: However, if developing directly on the device isn't your main aim and you're happy to develop on a desktop then eMbedded Visual C++ is an ok development environment and it is free. Not sure I can help you much beyond that... Windows CE 3.0 is unsupported as of 2007 so I doubt you'll find all that much out there for it...

Comment: Thanks, but i'm goiing to use the trial version of PocketC. Thanks

Comment: This answer says nothing about running compilers on the Jornada. Also, PocketC is only for Palm right?

Answer (score 1):

Neat. I think I had one of those, or something similar. (Unfortunately, mine had a defect where it would reboot if the keyboard flexed.)

Some people install NetBSD on those. You could probably use gcc if you did that. I'd see if I could get Linux or NetBSD running on it.

I don't remember a native C for it, but maybe there's one now. Googling "gcc jornada" turns up some hits. Keep looking.